# jQuery.validate does not validate dropdown with selectbox() javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-selectbox

I am having several drop-down in my HTML and I am using jQuery Selectbox plugin (selectbox()) for customized drop-down.

Also I need to validate the form, for which I am using jQuery.validate js.

When I apply the `selectbox()` like `$("#pd_subject").selectbox();` to the dropdowns jQuery.validate does not validate the dropdown at all,

**Fiddle Case 1** : [Case1](http://jsfiddle.net/UKDbq/)

but when I remove the selectbox() property from dropdowns, jQuery.validate starts validating them.

**Fiddle Case 2** : [Case2](http://jsfiddle.net/UKDbq/1/)

What could be the hurdle in first case??

Comment: Put your code in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

The Latest jQuery.validate.js (1.9.0 & more) ignores the hidden fields and only validates the visible fields on the form.

```
> ignore: ":hidden",
```

Where as the older version of validate.js (1.8.1 & less) has this line:

```
> ignore: [],
```

Which includes every field on the form, whether it is visible or not.

The selectbox() plugin simply hides the drop-down and adds new div in the HTML supporting the design and customization

```
<select id="qwerty" name="qwerty" sb="55594954" style="display: none;">...</select>
<div id="sbHolder_55594954" class="sbHolder">.....</div>
```

and that's why the dropdown keep escaping from validation.

Updated fiddle with old validate.js here: http://jsfiddle.net/UKDbq/2/